# What is the use of google tag manager for iOS app?

Tags: ios, google-tag-manager

I am using firebase Analytics to log all the event. I m not able to understand the google tag manager , How can i use it . What google tag manager can do for iOS app.

Comment: Read this  https://medium.com/@jev/10-cool-things-you-can-do-with-google-tag-manager-7f1d59d794f5

Comment: this is for web.

Answer (score 0):

One of the big iOS/Android projects I work on uses GTM variables for remote configuration.

For example, our menu items change based on whether it is Winter. So, we flip a boolean on GTM, and voila, within 24 hours, all our apps have the correct menu items.

We are planning to migrate this functionality to Firebase database, however, which has the benefit of instant updates.